# Could once_flag be movable?

Tags: c++, c++11

How does it come, the standard says nothing about the movable'ity of once_flag? I would expect the same arguments to apply as for std::mutex. At least for gcc (version 4.8) moving seems to be disabled. If a certain compiler would allow moving, one could end up with non-portable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synopsis is (§30.4 [thread.mutex])

```
struct once_flag {
    constexpr once_flag() noexcept;
    once_flag(const once_flag&) = delete;
    once_flag& operator=(const once_flag&) = delete;
};
```

Since the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are user-declared (and explicitly deleted), the move constructor and move assignment operator are not implicitly declared (§12.8 [class.copy]/p9, 20):

> 9 If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only
>   if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.
>
> 20 If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move
>   assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if
>   and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Hence, `once_flag` cannot be moved.

Comment: The standardese regarding the implicit declaration of a move cosntructor is in [class.copy]/9.